# Getting Column-Names to Wrap in R/Kable() HTML Table

Tags: r, html-table, knitr, xtable

I'm trying to produce an HTML table output from an R data frame and am unable to get some long column names to wrap for a multi-line header row. Here is a minimal reproducible example of my current code and output:

```
library(datasets)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

data(iris)
```

Output top 5 rows of iris table as html formatted table:

```
sink('my_file_path.html')
names_spaced <- c('Sepal Length', 'Sepal Width', 'Petal Length', 
                  'Petal Width Long Col Name', 'Species')

kable(head(iris), 
      format='html', 
      digits=1, 
      row.names=FALSE, 
      align='lccccc', 
      col.names = names_spaced)

sink()
```

When I open the saved file in the browser, my header row is just one line, but I need the words to wrap to one or two lines (hence `'Petal Width Long Col Name'`).

`kable_styling` function has a param `bootstrap_options` but that doesn't seem to have what I need. I also tried inserting `\n` within the column-names but to no avail.

I am not averse to using the `xtable` package instead of `kable`/`knitr` if that's part of the solution.

Comment: Please load all libraries that are required to run your code in the question. I guess you meant to use `kable` from the `knitr` library?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is possible to create linebreaks with HTML syntax. In order for that to work, you will have to set the `escape` argument of `kable` to `FALSE`.

```
library(knitr)
data(iris)

sink('my_file_path.html')
names_spaced <- c(
  'Sepal Length', 'Sepal Width', 'Petal Length', 
  'Petal Width<br/> Long Col Name',                  ## add <br/>
  'Species')

kable(head(iris), 
      format='html', 
      digits=1, 
      row.names=FALSE, 
      align='lccccc', 
      col.names = names_spaced,
      escape = FALSE)                                ## disable html escape to 
                                                     ## make <br/> work

sink()
```

Comment: thanks a lot man, works perfectly. Elegant and customizable (easy to control exactly where line breaks happen). `?kable` documentation for `escape` param says `escape special characters when producing HTML or LaTeX tables`. That's a little ambiguous to me. Can that be used to render other html tags like e.g. <strong> in a string column value?

Comment: I think it does altough I only worked with similar frameworks in the past -- not with `kable` itself

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Can I ask what your preferred tool for creating HTML tables from r dataframes is?

Comment: It is `datatable` from the package `DT`. I strongly suggest you to check it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147882/discussion-between-gregor-de-cillia-and-max-power).

Comment: Hello! Thank you very much for your answer. Is there an equivalent of <br/> for pdf/LaTex? When I use <br/>, the results show perfectly when I run them in the console but they fail to print in a pdf output. Thanks so much!